# Is there a way where the same ID from a bucket of IDs do not get assigned to multiple requests

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with Lead IDs which is a master list of IDs say from 1 to 10. A user can get only one ID from this list by clicking on "Get Lead" from a web application. This application executes a stored procedure by passing the userID to the stored procedure.
When user A clicks on the button "Get Lead" then the ID of A is passed to the stored procedure, and the procedure returns any id ID from 1 to 10 and inserts into a table which saves the userID and the LeadID. 
If any ID is already assigned to a user then the same ID cannot be assigned to another user.

I've 2 problems when executing the stored

### Problem 1

The same Lead ID gets assigned multiple times to the same user at the same time

### Problem 2

Even though the Lead ID is assgined to User A, the same Lead ID gets assigned to User B as well.

Following is the code that I have used

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[LeadAssign]
@UserID INT = NULL
As
Begin

    DECLARE @AlreadyAssigned AS INT
    SET @AlreadyAssigned = 0
    /*Checking whether there is any lead ID assigned to the user with status = 0*/
    select @AlreadyAssigned = X.ID from
    (
        select top 1 nfr.ID
        from Leads nfr where nfr.UserEntityID = @UserID
        and status = 0 /*which means that this lead is not yet closed and the user is still working on it*/
    )X

    IF (@AlreadyAssigned = 0) 
    BEGIN
        select top 1 LeadID from #LeadList /*This contains the list of all LEAD Ids which is not yet assigned to any user*/
        insert into Leads(LeadID, UserEntityID, Status) VALUES (LeadID, @UserID, 0)
    END
END
```

Comment: I would suggest that you read a couple of articles to help make this question better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a transaction, and use a lock hint lock when checking if the row already exists.  The right lock hint is (updlock, holdlock) which will place a U lock on the target row, or target range if no row exists.  That way if two sessions call the procedure at the same time, one will run and the other will wait until the other is complete *before* checking to see if the lead is already assigned.

So something like this:

```
create or alter procedure [dbo].[LeadAssign]
@UserID INT = NULL
As
Begin
    begin transaction

    DECLARE @AlreadyAssigned AS INT
    SET @AlreadyAssigned = 0
    /*Checking whether there is any lead ID assigned to the user with status = 0*/
    select @AlreadyAssigned = X.ID from
    (
        select top 1 nfr.ID
        from Leads nfr with (updlock, holdlock)
        where nfr.UserEntityID = @UserID
        and status = 0 /*which means that this lead is not yet closed and the user is still working on it*/
    )X

    IF (@AlreadyAssigned = 0) 
    BEGIN
        select top 1 LeadID from #LeadList /*This contains the list of all LEAD Ids which is not yet assigned to any user*/
        insert into Leads(LeadID, UserEntityID, Status) VALUES (LeadID, @UserID, 0)
    END

    commit transaction
END
```